# I am trying to retrieve the posts via ajax call but Wordpress Ajax gives server error 500

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

When I click on pagination link (page number) it gives me post_type, taxonomy, term_name. I passed the variables with JQuery Variables to Ajax wordpress function. The Ajax function is receiving the vaiables. But WP_Query loop does not work with the passed data.

JavaScript Code:

```
<script>
 $(".category--pagination").on("click", "a", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    if (link.indexOf("/page/") >= 0) {
      brands_page = parseInt(link.substr(link.indexOf("/page/") + 6, 4));
    } else {
      brands_page = 1;
    }
    mzm_filter_taxonomy();
  });

  //  mzm_filter_tax

  function mzm_filter_taxonomy() {
    $("#brandCategoryItemDisplay").addClass("loading");
    var post_type = $("#post_type").val();
    var taxonomy = $("#taxonomy").val();
    var term_slug = $("#term_slug").val();
    var term_name = $("#term_name").val();
    //console.log(post_type);
   // console.log(taxonomy);
   // console.log(term_name);
   if (brands_page == undefined) {
    brands_page = 1;
  }
    var data = {
      action: "mzm_filter_taxonomy",
      post_type: post_type,
      taxonomy:taxonomy,
      term_slug:term_slug,
      term_name:term_name,
      page:brands_page,

    };

    $.post(mzm_filter.ajax_url, data, function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      if (response.success) {
        console.log("executed success");
        $("#brandCategoryItemDisplay").removeClass("loading");
        $("#brandCategoryItemDisplay").html(response.data.items);

        $(".category--pagination").html(response.data.pagination);
        //$("#taxonomy_pagination").html(response.data.pagination);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Wordpress Ajax Function:

```
function mzm_filter_taxonomy()
{
    $post_type   = isset($_POST['post_type']) ? filter_var(trim($_POST['post_type']), FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS) : null;
    $taxonomy   = isset($_POST['taxonomy']) ? filter_var(trim($_POST['taxonomy']), FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS) : null;
    $term_slug   = isset($_POST['term_slug']) ? filter_var(trim($_POST['term_slug']), FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS) : null;
    $term_name   = isset($_POST['term_name']) ? filter_var(trim($_POST['term_name']), FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS) : null;
    $perpage  = mzm_brand_perpage();
    $paged    = (isset($_POST['page']) && intval($_POST['page'])) ? intval($_POST['page']) : 1;
    // $sort     = ( isset( $_POST['sort'] ) && intval( $_POST['sort'] ) ) ? intval( $_POST['sort'] ) : 1;
   // $sort     = (isset($_POST['sort'])) ? intval($_POST['sort']) : 1;
    // $args     = array(
    //     'post_type'      => $post_type,
    //     'hide_empty'     => false,
    //     'posts_per_page' => $perpage,
    //     'paged'          => $paged,
    //     'post_status' => 'publish',
    //     'tax_query' => array(
    //         array (
    //             'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    //             'field' => 'slug',
    //             'terms' => $term_slug,
    //         )
    //     ),
    // );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array (
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $term_slug,
            )
        ),
    ) );
   // $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
    ob_start();
    // echo $post_type . '<br>';
    // echo $taxonomy . '<br>';
    // echo $term_name . '<br>';
    // echo $term_slug . '<br>';
    if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
        while ($the_query->have_posts()) {
            the_post();
           // echo mzm_render_single_brand_card();
           echo the_title();
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
        echo '<div class="no-criteria-search">Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</div>';
    }
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    $result = array(
        'items' => $html,
        'pagination' => 'mzm_render_pagination($the_query)',
    );
    wp_send_json_success($result);
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_mzm_filter_taxonomy', 'mzm_filter_taxonomy');
add_action('wp_ajax_mzm_filter_taxonomy', 'mzm_filter_taxonomy');
```

[image]

I am trying paginate via Ajax request. Other all scripts are working. But this is a single taxonomy page. On this page the loop doesn't executes. It gives server error 500.

Comment: What does your server's error log tell you about this? If an error 500 occurs, there's usually something written to the log, if not to the response itself. What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: what error do you see on the server

Comment: There are no error server log file. I already checked.

Comment: When i echo the  passed variables into ajax function. I receive the correct data. But when i use this data to generate WP_Query, then the ajax function returns 500 server error.

Comment: Then you need to check why this happens. If no log file is generated, check your server configuration about how to enable this log

Comment: 500 is a server side error and can be found in your error log

Comment: I think the error is coming from query. Because when i print something else then query, it works. But with query it doesn't work. The query request is coming from single custom taxonomy page.

Comment: Then you should check for the error message and resolve it. Unless you post it here, it's close to impossible to tell you why this error occurs

Comment: You're using `echo the_title()` inside your loop. This is probably your error.  `the_title()` already echoes the output unless you specify otherwise.  Also, instead of using pure PHP functions `filter_var` use wordpress `sanitize_` your input fields.

Comment: How i can find the error ?  Can i use the following code ? **ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);**

Comment: Why not try it out and see what happens? That could already help

Comment: I tried to use this code. But nothing happened. I used the code in functions.php file.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I solved it myselft.  **the_post();
//should be
$the_query->the_post();**

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself.

The problem was in wp_query loop. I using custom $args and the loop object was $the_query.

So,

```
the_post();
//should be
$the_query->the_post();
```